# How do I perform lookup or an indexed match in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula

In a `Worksheet` I have a large list of Clients (e.g. in column A) each with their own specific project number (in column B).

In another `Worksheet` within the same `Workbook` I would like to display in one cell (e.g. `B1`) the exact project number that corresponds with the name of the client I input into another cell (e.g. A1). If I input a client name that doesn't show up on my client list, nothing will display.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understood you correctly.

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function:

```
(in cell B1)
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, LookupSheet!A:B, 2, FALSE), "")
```

In `VLOOKUP`, the `2` in the third argument states that if the lookup value in `A1` is found in the first column of the lookup range, you want to return the value in the second column. The fourth argument `FALSE` forces the match to be exact (this also makes sure that you don't have to sort the list).

If the lookup fails, then `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`. The `IFERROR` function checks if the first argument gives an error, such as `#N/A` - if not it returns the value, otherwise it returns the second argument (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a VLOOK function in the B1 cell. You have to set the parameters

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

In your case these are the parameters:

- **lookup_value** = A1
- **table_array** = the first two column of the tab where you have the list of clients and ID
- **col_index_num** = 2
- **range_lookup** = 0

In the end, you can just take a glance at these [page 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) and [page 2](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm) to have an idea of how this function works.

Answer (score 0):

Enter client name in cell `A1` on second Worksheet.
Assume the data is on a sheet called `Data`

In cell `B1`, enter: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(A1,Data!A:A,0)),"")`

Breaking this down:

`=IFERROR({function} ,"")` this says if my function returns an error, print nothing
`INDEX(Data!B:B, MATCH(A1,Data!A:A ,0))` this has two args:

1. The data you wish to reproduce is from column `B` on `Worksheet`
   'Data'
2. The MATCH function (see below)

`MATCH(A1,Data!A:A,0)` has three args:

1. The name to match is in cell `A1` on the same `Worksheet`
2. The `Range` to find that name in is on `Worksheet` named 'Data' in column `A`
3. The `0` indicates that only exact matches should be accepted

Comment: Success!  This one is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you use `INDEX( ... MATCH ( .. ) )` if `VLOOKUP` will do?